# Resolve day of the year c++

Tags: c++

i'm new at programming and i'm currently taking C++

I have this code and for example if i'm input `2018 2 32` the output must be `0`, but now the output is `62` and i don't know how to resolve this. I need help and wonder if someone can take a look at my code and tell me what is wrong with it?

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// pointer
const int january = 31;
const int february = 28;
const int isLeapFeb = 29;
const int march = 31;
const int april = 30;
const int may = 31;
const int june =30;
const int july = 31;
const int august = 31;
const int september = 30;
const int october = 31;
const int november = 30;
const int december = 31;


bool isLeap(int year) {
// menentukan tahun kabisat dan biasa
    return (((year % 4) == 0) && (((year % 100) != 0) || ((year % 400) == 0)));
}

int monthLength(int year, int month, int day) {
                // bulan dengan hari 31
                if((month == 1) || (month == 3) || (month == 5) || (month == 7) || (month || 8) || (month == 10) || (month || 12))
            {
                if((day > 0) && (day < 32))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            // bulan dengan hari 30
            if((month == 4) || (month == 6) || (month == 9) || (month == 11))
            {
                if((day > 0) && (day < 31))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            if(month == 2) // februari 28 hari
            {
                if((day > 0) && (day < 29))     
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            if((isLeap(year))) // februari 29 hari
            {
                if((month == 2) && ((day > 0) && (day < 30)))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
}

int dayOfYear(int year, int month, int day) {
// tahun 1582 Gregorian kalender mulai
        int dayTotal = 0;

        if(monthLength(year, month, day)) 
        {
            if(month == 1)
            {
                dayTotal = 0 + day;
            }

            if(month == 2)
            {
                dayTotal = january + day;
            }

            if((month == 3) && (year > 1582))
            {
                dayTotal = january + february + day;

                if((month == 3) && (year > 1582) && (isLeap(year)))
                {
                    dayTotal = january + isLeapFeb + day;
                }
            }

            if((month == 4) && (year > 1582))
            {
                dayTotal = january + february + march + day;

                if((month == 4) && (year > 1582) && (isLeap(year)))
                {
                    dayTotal = january + isLeapFeb + march + day;
                }
            }

            if((month == 5) && (year > 1582))
            {
                dayTotal = january + february + march + april + day;

                if((month == 5) && (year > 1582) && (isLeap(year)))
                {
                    dayTotal = january + isLeapFeb + march + april + day;
                }
            }

            if((month == 6) && (year > 1582))
            {
                dayTotal = january + february + march + april + may + day;

                if((month == 6) && (year > 1582) && (isLeap(year)))
                {
                    dayTotal = january + isLeapFeb + march + april + may + day;
                }
            }

            if((month == 7) && (year > 1582))
            {
                dayTotal = january + february + march + april + may + june + day;

                if((month == 7) && (year > 1582) && (isLeap(year)))
                {
                    dayTotal = january + isLeapFeb + march + april + may + june + day;
                }
            }

            if((month == 8) && (year > 1582))
            {
                dayTotal = january + february + march + april + may + june + july + day;

                if((month == 8) && (year > 1582) && (isLeap(year)))
                {
                    dayTotal = january + isLeapFeb + march + april + may + june + july + day;
                }
            }

            if((month == 9) && (year > 1582))
            {
                dayTotal = january + february + march + april + may + june + july + august + day;

                if((month == 9) && (year > 1582) && (isLeap(year)))
                {
                    dayTotal = january + isLeapFeb + march + april + may + june + july + august + day;
                }
            }

            if((month == 10) && (year > 1582))
            {
                dayTotal = january + february + march + april + may + june + july + august + september + day;

                if((month == 10) && (year > 1582) && (isLeap(year)))
                {
                    dayTotal = january + isLeapFeb + march + april + may + june + july + august + september + day;
                }
            }

            if((month == 11) && (year > 1582))
            {
                dayTotal = january + february + march + april + may + june + july + august + september + october + day;

                if((month == 11) && (year > 1582) && (isLeap(year)))
                {
                    dayTotal = january + isLeapFeb + march + april + may + june + july + august + september + october + day;
                }
            }

            if((month == 12) && (year > 1582))
            {
                dayTotal = january + february + march + april + may + june + july + august + september + october + november + day;

                if((month == 5) && (year > 1582) && (isLeap(year)))
                {
                    dayTotal = january + isLeapFeb + march + april + may + june + july + august + september + october + november + day;
                }
            }
        }

    return dayTotal;
}

int main(void) {
int day, month, year;
cout << "Enter year month day: ";
cin >> year >> month >> day;
cout << dayOfYear(year, month, day) << endl;
return 0;
}
```

It compile but the output is not correct.  I really appreciate your help and feedback. Thank you very much

Comment: Please add the input/output in textual form to your post. A link is strongly discouraged.

Comment: Use a debugger and step into your dayOfYear() and see if your expected code path is executed.

Comment: Turn up your warnings levels. I'm confident `(month || 8) ` is *not* something you intended, and it certainly isn't something you want. Same goes for `(month || 12)`. It is causing the vast majority of `monthLength` to always be skipped. And `monthLength` claims to return `int`. So why are you returning `bool` values ? Finally, that function has a code path with no assigned return result, so it is broken regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because your are passing `days` as `31` and when this line executed:

```
       if(month == 2)
        {
            dayTotal = january + day;
        }
```

Then

```
            dayTotal = 31 + 31;  // = 62 which is what you see.
```

You need to use the debugger to discover such errors, beside you need to add some validations to prevent invalid data such as `02/31/2018`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Based on suggestions from @Slava, I have revised my answer. This implementation uses a single regular expression match to validate and to extract the components of the date. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

void parseDate(const string& date, int& year, int& month, int& day)
{
    regex dateValidateRe(R"(^(\d{4})\-(\d{1,2})\-(\d{1,2})$)");
    smatch matches;
    if (!regex_search(date, matches, dateValidateRe))
    {
        throw invalid_argument("Date format is incorrect");
    }
    year = stoi(matches[1]);
    month = stoi(matches[2]);
    day = stoi(matches[3]);
}

int main()
{
    int year, month, day;
    string date;
    cin >> date;
    try
    {
        parseDate(date, year, month, day);
    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        cout << "Invalid input: " << ex.what() << endl;
    }
    cout << "The date entered was Year = " << year << " Month = " << month << " Day = " << day << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a [working demo](https://ideone.com/1P9GQj)

** Original Response **

You're not parsing your input correctly. Your input is `2018-2-31` is being parsed as year 2018, month -2, and day -31. You need to parse your date as a string and then break that string apart by the token `-` to extract year, month, and day.

Here is a quick and dirty function that you can use to parse the input correctly:

```
void parseDate(const string& date, int& year, int& month, int& day)
{
    auto ypos = date.find("-");
    string syear = date.substr(0, ypos);
    auto mpos = date.find("-", ypos+1);
    string smonth = date.substr(ypos+1, mpos-ypos-1);
    string sday = date.substr(mpos+1);
    year = stoi(syear);
    month = stoi(smonth);
    day = stoi(sday);
}
```

Update your main as follows:

```
int main(void) {
int day, month, year;
cout << "Enter year month day: ";
string date;
cin >> date;
parseDate(date, year, month, day);
cout << dayOfYear(year, month, day) << endl;
return 0;
}
```

This should give you the right results. Please update parseDate so it validates the input string before it proceeds to tokenize it.

Comment: I think regexp here would be better

Comment: How about this: https://ideone.com/pz014P?

Comment: Not quite, you should use the same expression to validate and to parse

Comment: Got it: https://ideone.com/1P9GQj